# Looping on more than one variable (not all of them are finite or even known sequences) in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, generator

How to loop on more than one variable in python if not all of them are already known or finite sequences?

In other words, How to create a similar code to this **C++** code in **python**?

```cpp
int y = 7;
int z = 3, dz = 5;
for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x, ++y, z += dz){
    cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << endl;
}
```

In this example, x boundaries are well defined. However, y and z are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do that by combining 2 features in python: the builtin function `zip()` and the `generator functions`.

I first defined a generator `increment_by(base, addon)`
as follows:

```py
def increment_by(base, addon):
    while True:
        yield base
        base += addon
```

Then I passed it, along with other generators / sequences to the zip function.
Finally I loop on the next value from zip().

N.B. One of the sequences  generators should be finite, otherwise, your application might crash.

```py
y, z, dz = 7, 3, 5
print('==>', y, z)
for x, y, z in zip(range(20), increment_by(y, 1), increment_by(z, dz)):
    print(x, y, z)
print()
print('==>', y, z)
```

The output was

```
==> 7 3
0 7 3
1 8 8
2 9 13
3 10 18
4 11 23
5 12 28
6 13 33
7 14 38
8 15 43
9 16 48
10 17 53
11 18 58
12 19 63
13 20 68
14 21 73
15 22 78
16 23 83
17 24 88
18 25 93
19 26 98
==> 26 98
```

The nice thing here is that by using the same variable name before the `in` operator, I can use the same variable value within and after the loop. This is possible because the interpreter takes the generator object, invoke `next()` on it, and return with the yielded value to in a way suitable for assignment to any variable, including the original variable itself. Hence, using the original variable will make its value get updated every iteration, and stay updated outside the loop.

**UPDATE:** As @Iain Shelvington mentioned, there is a builtin generator function (`itertools.count(start=0, step=1)`) that does exactly the same functionality and it takes the same parameters in the same order as `increment_by(base, addon)`.

Comment: Your `increment_by` has a function in the std lib that does the same job: `itertools.count`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about it. It is simple and useful.